# FireDAC Filter no delphi não funciona com acento

Tags: delphi, filter, firedac

Ao pesquisar:

```
AQuery.Filter := 'nome LIKE ''%jose%''';
```

O resultado José da Silva não é mostrado devido ao acento na letra é.

Pesquisei vários assuntos relacionados e percebi que:

A chamada MySQL funciona normal quando estou usando meu gestor de banco de dados.

```
SELECT * FROM pessoas
WHERE nome LIKE '%jose%'
```

Esse comando me retorna como o esperado o José da Silva.

Fazendo a chamada com SELECT no delphi funciona.

```
AQuery.Open('SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE nome LIKE ''%jose%''');
Esse comando me retorna como o esperado o José da Silva.
```

Fazendo a chamada com Filter no delphi NÃO funciona

```
Filter := 'nome LIKE ''%jose%''';
```

Esse comando NÃO me retorna o José da Silva.

Problema

Eu só não obtenho o que desejo quando uso o Filter, então há algum problema nesse método.

Soluções

Tentei várias soluções, dentre elas o comando.

```
Filter := 'Upper(nome_pessoa) like '+QuotedStr('%'+ AnsiUpperCase(Texto)+'%');
Porém, não tive sucesso.
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que esteja usando um TFDQuery(Firedac), segundo a documentação da [Embarcadero](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Filtering_Records_(FireDAC))
deve usar por exemplo:

```
  AQuery.Open;
  AQuery.Filtered:= False;
  AQuery.Filter:= ' nome LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+Texto+'%');
  AQuery.Filtered:= True;
```

Funcionou com sucesso pra mim.